# Unable to install "tidytext" and "jasonlite" packages in rstudio

Tags: r, tidytext

I have tried the following:

1. `install.packages("tidytext")`
2. ````
   library(remotes)
   install_github("juliasilge/tidytext")```
   ````
3. ```
   install.packages(c("mnormt", "psych", "SnowballC", "hunspell", "broom", "tokenizers", "janeaustenr"))
   install.packages("tidytext")
   ```
4. `install.packages("jsonlite")`

Comment: which error message does it give?

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured it out:

```
install.packages('tidytext', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
install.packages('jsonlite', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```